# Why Meliodas regenerations abilities didnt work in his first fight with Gilthunder?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In Meliodas first fight with Gilthunder, he gets injured and he's taken by his friends with his doctor. But he is a member of the demon clan who's even capable of reattaching a cut arm, and it's shown later in the anime.

Why Meliodas regenerations abilities didnt work in his first fight with Gilthunder?

Comment: If I recall correctly by that time his true power is sealed and when he fought Gilthunder his power level is around 3000 to 3500 making him to be more weaker same goes for his regeneration abilities.

Answer (score -1):

His powers were sealed, because back then his power level was significantly lowered.Back then, his powers were sealed because he couldn't control his emotions after he destroyed Danafor because Liz died.
In chapter 29, Melodias has a flashback about Danafor, which he destroyed in his wrath.